# ¿Cómo recibir inputs text con valores mayores a 1?

Tags: php, html

Tengo una serie de `<input>` generados por un `while` de acuerdo a la cantidad de elementos que traigo de una base de datos.

El `<input>` es para poner la cantidad de platos a comprar, entonces al hacer clic en un botón enviar necesito recibir todos los `<input>` donde el cliente haya elegido 1 o más platos. Además de recibir los datos de ese plato como su nombre y precio.

Algo así como esta página: https://fs22.formsite.com/shogunparties/form1/index.html.

Pero no tengo idea de como hacer eso, estaba pensando hacer algún bucle. Espero me haya dejado entender y puedan ayudarme.

Éste es mi código como traigo los `<input>` de la base de datos:

```
<form action="reserva" method="post"> <div class="plates">
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($platos)) { ?>
<p class="plate__name"><?php echo $row ['name_plate'];?></p>
<p class="plate__price"><?php echo number_format($row ['price_plate'], 2);?></p> 
<input type="text" class="plate__input" value="0" name="<?php echo $row ['id_plate'];?>">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row ['price_plate'];?>"</div>
```

Deseo recibirlo en php a través de `post` y guardar en variables solo los `<input>` que tengan valor de 1 o más.

Comment: ¿Cual es el problema que tienes exactamente? ¿no sabes como recoger el valor en php o no sabes como recoger solo los que tienen valor > 1?

Comment: ¿Deseas hacerlo en el lado del servidor o en el lado del cliente? En principio no supone ningún problema recibir un formulario con valor "0" ya que al multiplicar un valor por 0, saldrá 0 como resultado.

Comment: No se como recibirlo en el php, porque los input son generados por un while. Y solo guardar en variables los que hayan escrito 1 o más. Gracias.

Comment: A parte de que ese código tiene errores PHP (no puedes poner un `while` de PHP sin abrir previamente código PHP con `<?php`) no tienes un `<input>` para gestionar el número de platos. Por favor, completa el código para poder reproducir tu problema y así nos facilitarás la tarea de corregir tu código. También nos facilitaría la tarea tener el PHP que recibe el formulario.